# cannot understand the following code in android

Tags: android

```
    ss.setSpan(new URLSpan("tel:1234556"), 13, 17,
            Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    tv.setText(ss);
    tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

what does the linkMovementMethod do?
what is the URLSpan class and what is the use of it? what does the string tel:123456 mean?
Is tel a keyword?

Need answer asap
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LinkMovementMethod controls how the text view scrolls through its content. It manages focus transfer between links. URLSpan creates a dynamic link (like the <a> tag in HTML); in this case to a telephone number. See the docs on the [Android Intents List](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html).